# Printing all lines of a file with multiple columns in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, sed, awk

I have a file with 4 columns with the below format:

```
name;user_id;dob;date_of_joining
```

I want to print all the variables in below output via shell script

> The employee "$name" is having "$user_id" whose date of birth is "$dob" and joined organisation on "$date_of_joining"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

> `awk -F\; '{print("The employee", $1, "is having", $2, "whose date of birth is", $3, "and joined organisation on", $4)}' filename`

where the filename is `filename`.

Answer (score 2):

With the shell, you can grab multiple fields from a line using the `read` command an manipulating the `IFS` variable:

```
while IFS=';' read -r name user_id dob joined; do
    echo "The employee $name is having $user_id whose date of birth is $dob and joined organisation on $joined"
done < filename
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `done` instead of `end`?